# how to add allowed method signature to in-script code in jenkins

Tags: http, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I'm running Jenkins pipeline and I want to add a HTTP post request.
I want to use Groovy/Java native code(I don't want to run curl with *sh* as its very **breakable**)

I'm running the following piece of code in the last step:

```
def builder = new groovy.json.JsonBuilder()


    builder {
        context 'branch_regression'
        state stateStr
    }

    Proxy proxy = new Proxy(Proxy.Type.HTTP, new InetSocketAddress("some-proxy.com", 912))
    def post = new URL(config.CommitStatusUpdateURL).openConnection(proxy)

    def message = builder.toString();
    post.setRequestMethod("POST")
    post.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic Some64BaseTokEAsfn")
    post.setDoOutput(true)
    post.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json")
    def rawdata = message.getBytes("UTF-8")
    def stream = post.getOutputStream()
    stream.write(rawdata);

    def postRC = post.getResponseCode();
    println(postRC);
    if(postRC.equals(200)) {
        println(post.getInputStream().getText());
```

But I then I got

> Scripts not permitted to use new java.net.InetSocketAddress java.lang.String int Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

with a link approve this method signature.. and I approved it and I'm running the task again and then I get:

> Scripts not permitted to use new java.net.Proxy java.net.Proxy$Type java.net.SocketAddress Administrators can decide whether to approve or reject this signature.

Its driving me nuts... What is the problem here??

Comment: Use curl :)
You may wrap it in try/catch clause and add some retry if you are afraid of stability probems.

Comment: Curl breaks.. if you try to pass body it always fails.. I specifically mentioned that I don't want to use Curl..

Comment: Then use `wget`. Don't reinvent wheel because then you'll need to maintain it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to approve the use of these functions in your scripts by going to `https://your.jenkins.url/scriptApproval/`. Every time you run a new script it will get to the first unapproved thing and fail, so this might go on for a bit.

Comment: i approve and approve and approve.. and it just keeps on going..

Comment: If you find that you approve new functions every time, this is going to end at some time. Alternatively, you might want to use `curl` :-)

Comment: is there a way to add all permission in advance instead of waiting for the task to fail and click the link?

Comment: Sadly, no. Security is high on Jenkins authors mindset.

Answer (score 0):

Move the HTTP code into a [global shared library](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#global-shared-libraries):

> These libraries are considered "trusted:" they can run any methods in
>   Java, Groovy, Jenkins internal APIs, Jenkins plugins, or third-party
>   libraries. This allows you to define libraries which encapsulate
>   individually unsafe APIs in a higher-level wrapper safe for use from
>   any Pipeline.